# The landscape mode of my image is congested - how solve it?

Tags: android

In the Android application landscape mode of the image is congested how solve it? code snippet as follows

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgOne"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: modify your question, 
add screenshots, and what are you expecting in landscape mode

Answer (score 0):

Should replace Match_parent to wrap_content

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</HorizontalScrollView>
```